# WooCommerce add new row in cart & checkout to show subtotal after discount applied

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, cart, checkout

Cart Total
[image]

So I am no expert and tried to solve my problem without any luck. I want to add a row between "Discount" and "shipping" that shows a subtotal of the cart with the discount deducted from it. It would be great to add it to the cart and checkout page.

I tried this to add another Row on the cart page and it worked, but I couldn't for the sake of god find out, how to display the new amount. [subtotal - discount = new subtotal]

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_custom_text', 'action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 10, 0 ); 

function action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping(  ) {
     echo "<tr class='cart-subtotal'><th>Title</th><td>Text</td></tr>";
}
```